# Laravel 5.1 DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 45: The payload is invalid

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a L5.1 app that uses jquery datatables with ajax datasources. All of them work fine apart from one that causes the server to throw an exception when it posts the ajax request to get the data. The error I'm getting is:

```
DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 45:
The payload is invalid.
```

I think this possibly has something to do with how much data the ajax request is posting since this particular datatable posts more data than the others. Also it must have something to do with CSRF protection because if I exclude the route from CSRF then it works fine.

Here are the headers I'm sending through:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1589
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:gsScrollPos=; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.478522745.1445258590; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlVYckJ5RW5rcVFVUlU0RjJLYjNmOWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRzRPcG4wWEhsaHVsSGdFRzh0UnhWWU5kXC9Jd0F1YWNjK0poOW5TcVpWMHhSZ0l6MXNtWVdZZ1pJVHBrRUJpYkZuaENacUxsM2M4RkxKOGVoNG5BSGtnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJkNGUxOWM0NzQ2MThjNDg1OTg0MjIwYmY5NGNmZGEzNzc5ZjZiNmExYTQ1Yjk0YTc2YWRlMTYyZDI5OWQ5N2ZkIn0%3D; session=eyJpdiI6ImdpRXozUXBmT2lLRmhOSnU0QW9zTlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMmN3QXZWeVFqWEhMSmw1QTdIaEY4WU1EOEszM1RKQU0xTE00Z2I5VVh3RjNLSFpqQUZ6dDRYdU0rK3FVekhZXC9rZkNWakN4a0ZtOTMrYnZDS0doWHF3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0MDA3ZDgyNTI3MTY0ZDlmNjZjM2IzYmJjZTQ2NTc4ZjdiNDRjN2M4M2VhMWU1MDc2YzE1ZmM1MDA1M2NkNDZlIn0%3D
Host:local.thecraftchannel.tv
Origin:https://local.website.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://local.website.com/admin/shows/edit/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN:PGBwTUHVjIQJPuZHLhqX2yEJFl0srgP1J4lO2oJy
```

Here is the form data that is being sent through also with the request:

```
draw:1
columns[0][data]:0
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:1
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:2
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:3
columns[3][name]:
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:4
columns[4][name]:
columns[4][searchable]:true
columns[4][orderable]:true
columns[4][search][value]:
columns[4][search][regex]:false
columns[5][data]:5
columns[5][name]:
columns[5][searchable]:false
columns[5][orderable]:false
columns[5][search][value]:
columns[5][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:0
order[0][dir]:asc
start:0
length:10
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
product_ids[]:8
product_ids[]:5
product_ids[]:4
product_ids[]:3
product_ids[]:6
product_ids[]:9
product_ids[]:14
product_ids[]:11
product_ids[]:16
product_ids[]:21
product_ids[]:23
```

Anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the CSRF protection provided by Laravel, you have to specify the CSRF token in your requests.

To do this, you could do the following:

Add a meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And setup your jQuery to use this token for all ajax requests like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

**Original answer**

Since you have a lot of data maybe the column type in your database is too small and you are therefore getting this error.

Try to set the column to `longtext` instead of `text` in your migration and see if that works.

Comment: Where do you exactly store the data?

Comment: The datatable is showing a list of shows and shows have various other models linked to them such as products and presenters so its from various  tables in the database. As mentioned in the original post though I don't think this has anything to do with the data since if I disable CSRF protection it works fine. So it must be something that CSRF is doing that is causing this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally skipped that part. See my edited answer how to setup CSRF for Ajax requests with jQuery.

Comment: Ah this was the issue. I was already doing that but I had a typo and was sending through X-XSRF-TOKEN instead of X-CSRF-TOKEN

Thank!